# How to center text on android IconGenerator

Tags: android, bitmap, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, markerclusterer

I'm developing an app using lots of markers placed on the map, and I'm using a custom ClusterRenderer to show them. 
Problem is that I can't draw the cluster's size in the center of the custom marker icon, please see attached screenshot.
I've tried adding contentPadding to the IconGenerator, but still no luck, because of the changing number of digits shown. Could you please help me center the text on the generated icon?

Code:

```
 IconGenerator clusterIconGenerator = new IconGenerator(context);
 clusterIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_cluster);
 clusterIconGenerator.setBackground(clusterIcon);

@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<MyType> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

    Bitmap clusterIcon = clusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(clusterIcon));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### UPDATE

starting Apr 1, 2016 a prefix has been added to the Resources of the library 
so the id="text" has been changed to **"amu_text"**.

---

As stated in the library documentation :

> setContentView public void setContentView(View contentView) 
>     Sets the child view for the icon.
>    If the view contains a
>   TextView with the id "amu_text", operations such as
>   setTextAppearance(Context, int) and makeIcon(String) will  operate
>   upon that TextView .

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<Dashboard_Marker> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    IconGenerator TextMarkerGen = new IconGenerator(context);
    Drawable marker;
    int ClusterSize = cluster.getSize();

    marker = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cluster_red);
    TextMarkerGen.setBackground(marker);

    LayoutInflater myInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View activityView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.cluster_view, null, false);

    TextMarkerGen.setContentView(activityView);
    TextMarkerGen.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));

    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(TextMarkerGen.makeIcon());
    markerOptions.icon(icon);
}
```

with the layout cluster_view as  :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/amu_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

note :: the layout must contain one text view with an id = "amu_text"  in order for the icon generator to accept it , manipulate all the positioning you want in the layout .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I missed this part of the documentation, you're a lifesaver! Although this way the text still appeared in the top left corner of the cluster, as the layout didn't apply the marker icon's layout params or something, but at least I was able to customize it. My workaround was to change the layout to a FrameLayout and add a View with the marker image as a background, so the layout will expand to the correct size. It's true, that the textview will hide this View, and an extra element will be loaded into the memory, but it solved my issue, thanks again!

Comment: Whtat if I am using a shape as the background for that Cluster icon and thus I don't have any layouts for the cluster?

Comment: @KasparTr I never tried shapes , but you can as set a background image . as for the layout , you have to create one if you are planing to better control what is written on your cluster

Comment: For me it didn't worked for Textview id = "text". As per documentation the ID should be "amu_text". 
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/ui/IconGenerator.java

Comment: my answer has been updated with the new changes in the library , thanks