# Show marker labels along with default pin icon all the time on google maps for android platform

Tags: android, google-maps

I have multiple locations that I need to display on my map.
I want the info/label for each marker to display on the maps along with the pin icon whether the marker/pin is clicked or not by the user.
I have the following code to display the markers.

```
for (DepartmentLocation loc : departmentLocations) {
                if (loc != null && loc.getLatitude() != null && loc.getLongitude() != null) {
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());

                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(loc.getName());
                    markerOptions.visible(true);
                    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    marker.showInfoWindow();
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                    markers.add(marker);

                }
            }
```

But still, I see only the red pins and no labels beside the pin.
Here is how my maps look like. I can see only one info label, not the others.
[image]

I have tried using the IconGenerator from the map utils.

implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'

```
  for (DepartmentLocation loc : departmentLocations) {
                if (loc != null && loc.getLatitude() != null && loc.getLongitude() != null) {
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());

                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon(loc.getName())))
                            .position(latLng)
                            .title(loc.getName());
                    markerOptions.visible(true);
                    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    marker.showInfoWindow();
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                    markers.add(marker);

                }
            }
```

When I use iconfactory, I am unable to show both the pin and the info label.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows) is displayed at a time on GoogleMap. You can't display multiple InfoWindow at a time.

You have to use [IconGenerator](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/ui/IconGenerator.html) for that. You can set a view to IconGenerator and make a Bitmap form that view. You can make a view that contains both Marker and your InfoWindow View. Use that view to crate your Desired Marker.

You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32837054/1292557)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, there is a text saying that the info window is shown one at a time, so there is no way to do that:

> "An info window allows you to display information to the user when they
>   tap on a marker. ***Only one info window is displayed at a time***. If a
>   user clicks on a marker, the current info window will be closed and
>   the new info window will be displayed. Note that if the user clicks on
>   a marker that is currently showing an info window, that info window
>   closes and re-opens."

You can read more here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows