# How can I render a dynamically-generated map pin in a Xamarin.forms application on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm already using `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` and [following the discussion here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map-pin) have got markers drawn using my custom icons. However I have a requirement to add the name of the marked object to the marker.

It looks like the customisation supported in Xamarin's maps [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api) uses [BitmapDescriptorFactory](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory), which only allows "static" images (from resources, assets, files, or the built-in marker) to be used.

I see that native android apps [use the IconGenerator class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53104403/show-marker-labels-along-with-default-pin-icon-all-the-time-on-google-maps-for-a#53104557) from the [`com.google.maps.android.ui` package](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/ui/IconGenerator.html) to dynamically generate markers that contain text or other elements. However that class (indeed that whole package) doesn't seem to be bridged to Xamarin.

Is there a way that I can dynamically generate the map markers for my map on Android from within Xamarin.forms?

Comment: you can dynamically create a Bitmap and use FromBitmap, or just write the image to a file and create it from there

Comment: You could change the resource image in GetInfoContents method in runtime. The link below would be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62712258/xamarin-forms-maps-adding-image-dynamically-to-infowindow

Comment: @Jason this is what I ended up going with, thank you.