# Android : Cluster marker count not showing properly with custom marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I'm plotting multiple marker on map using [Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering) but my problem is that cluster marker count not showing on the proper place with custom marker. I have added image for the more clarification.

Below is loadmap()

```
private void LoadMap() {
        try {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                    gMap = mMap;
                    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    mMap.clear();
                    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(getActivity(), mMap);
                    //mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                    mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
                    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
                    mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MarkerClusterRenderer(getActivity(), mMap, mClusterManager));

                    if(arrayListLatLong.size() > 0) {
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(arrayListLatLong.get(0).getLatitude(), arrayListLatLong.get(0).getLongitude()), 10));
                        for (int i = 0; i < arrayListLatLong.size(); i++) {
                            ClusterMapItems offsetItem = new ClusterMapItems(arrayListLatLong.get(i).getLatitude(), arrayListLatLong.get(i).getLongitude(), arrayListLatLong.get(i).getVehicleStatus(),
                                    arrayListLatLong.get(i).getRegistrationId(), arrayListLatLong.get(i).getCurrentVehicleSpeed(), arrayListLatLong.get(i).getVehicleUpdateTimeStr(),
                                    arrayListLatLong.get(i).getGroupName(), arrayListLatLong.get(i).getVin(), arrayListLatLong.get(i).getDescription(), arrayListLatLong.get(i).getVehicleVariant(),
                                    arrayListLatLong.get(i).getAdblueLevel(), arrayListLatLong.get(i).getTotalFuelConsumption(), arrayListLatLong.get(i).getFuelTankLevel());
                            mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
                            mClusterManager.cluster();

                            mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<ClusterMapItems>() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onClusterItemClick(ClusterMapItems clusterMapItems) {
                                    MyFleetBottomSheetFragment bottomSheetFragment = new MyFleetBottomSheetFragment();
                                    Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putParcelable("clusterMapItems", clusterMapItems);
                                    bottomSheetFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                                    bottomSheetFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetFragment.getTag());
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(20.5937, 78.9629), 0));
                }
            });
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

MarkerClusterRenderer.Class

```
public class MarkerClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<ClusterMapItems> {


    private final IconGenerator iconGenerator;
    private Context contextN;

    public MarkerClusterRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<ClusterMapItems> clusterManager ) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
        iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(context);
        contextN = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getBucket(Cluster<ClusterMapItems> cluster) {
        return cluster.getSize();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(ClusterMapItems clusterItem, Marker marker) {
        super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(ClusterMapItems item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
            if(item.getVehicleStatus().equals("NEW")){
                BitmapDescriptor markerDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_green_pointer);
                markerOptions.icon(markerDescriptor);
            }

            if(item.getVehicleStatus().equals("RUNNING")){
                BitmapDescriptor markerDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_black_pointer);
                markerOptions.icon(markerDescriptor);
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<ClusterMapItems> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        final Drawable clusterIcon = contextN.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_cluster_purple);
        iconGenerator.setBackground(clusterIcon);
        iconGenerator.setTextAppearance(com.google.maps.android.R.style.amu_ClusterIcon_TextAppearance);
        Bitmap icon = iconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));

    }
}
```

Please help me out how can I show the cluster count in center of cluster marker? Is there any possibilities?

I have tried this given SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836595/how-to-center-text-on-android-icongenerator) still I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836595/how-to-center-text-on-android-icongenerator)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center text on android IconGenerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836595/how-to-center-text-on-android-icongenerator)

Comment: @MaratZangiev I have already tried the same SO answer but it didnt work for me that what I have asked the question.

Comment: You need to cpecify custom ```View``` for cluster instead of ```Drawable``` and it will work fine

Comment: try from answer

Answer (score 1):

Create custom `cluster_view.xml` layout for your Clusters:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/amu_text"
        android:gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

You should specify a `TextView` inside with id `amu_text`.

After that change your `Renderer` code as follow:

```
public class MarkerClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<ClusterMapItems> {


    private final IconGenerator iconGenerator;
    private Context contextN;

    public MarkerClusterRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<ClusterMapItems> clusterManager ) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
        iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(context);
        contextN = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getBucket(Cluster<ClusterMapItems> cluster) {
        return cluster.getSize();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(ClusterMapItems clusterItem, Marker marker) {
        super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(ClusterMapItems item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
            if(item.getVehicleStatus().equals("NEW")){
                BitmapDescriptor markerDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_green_pointer);
                markerOptions.icon(markerDescriptor);
            }

            if(item.getVehicleStatus().equals("RUNNING")){
                BitmapDescriptor markerDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_black_pointer);
                markerOptions.icon(markerDescriptor);
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<ClusterMapItems> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        final Drawable clusterIcon = contextN.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_cluster_purple);
        iconGenerator.setBackground(clusterIcon);
        LayoutInflater myInflater = (LayoutInflater)contextN.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View clusterView= myInflater.inflate(R.layout.cluster_view, null, false);
        iconGenerator.setContentView(clusterView);
        iconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));
        BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconGenerator.makeIcon());
        markerOptions.icon(icon);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marat Zangiev As per your answer and suggested link I have tried still issue is there you can check on this link https://imgur.com/a/trT7VhD

Comment: I tried many variations on this, and it seems like only way to implement it is to set background that have similar size with standard cluster icon size. Checkout more [there](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/ui/IconGenerator.java)